# JQuery plugin (or otherwise JS [or amazing alternative, like Flash]) for tree editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I'm tearing my hair out on this one; I want / need / would like something akin to one of the many tree viewers out there, but where I can also edit the structure, the name and the type of nodes (the world doesn't **just** have folders and files, people). I've Googled myself silly over this, looked at which plugin I could modify to do my bidding (not with much luck), but surely someone, somewhere must have had the need for an **editor** and not just a viewer? Surely someone must have more complex needs, like me?

The best one so far seems to be the [one from Bassistance](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/), but without the good editing part (just basic stuff). Is this the one I should extend, maybe?

I'm not married to JQuery, but the rest of my application use it and it would be the simplest, but if there's a Flash or other JS thing floating around, I'm cool. Input and output should be sane, and if you got a SQL backend, that's cool, too, but JSON or XML or whatever else that makes sense, er, makes sense.

Thoughts? Clues? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the tree from Joern Zafferer (bassistance) is good.

There is also this one. (it has editing + exemples for server-side code):
http://www.jstree.com/reference/_examples/1_datasources.html

Ultimately all these scripts should be merged and refactored for jquery-ui, in the meantime you can check [jqueryui.pbworks.com/Tree](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/Tree) to check the current state of things.

Comment: Yeah, the jstree plugin is really the closest so far. I find it very odd that there is no such thing as a typed tree editor; surely most applications would benefit from one. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=3). It has a tree grid and can be edited.

Look at the [demonstration page](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), New in version 3.3 -> Tree Grid.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the Tree Grid for other things, but it doesn't **edit** anything; that's an extension I'd have to make myself. It's a good plugin, though, but for other things.